# AWS Quicksight - Logic for connecting to DB and generating charts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

new to quicksight Embedded Analytics here,

I had a simple question around how quicksight generates the charts.

1. Is it through direct database queries or
2. Does it intercept API calls from my web app's backend?

For ex: My current application is working such that,

1. The front end makes API calls and displays the chart based on the API data
2. If certain filters (like date etc.) are changed from the UI, the API sends the new data based on the filter and the UI renders the new chart.

How does this scenario now work in AWS Quicksight embedded analytics.

1. Should I pass filters from my web app into quicksight. receive them as Quicksight Parameters/filters and allow quicksight to query the DB directly with the filters and render the charts?
2. Will Quicksight intercept the previously mentioned API that my backend is sending and display the charts?

Which one of the above happens?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Quicksight has below-supported data sources.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-data-sources.html

Quicksight has the feature of filtering data, based on controls/parameters. Please refer below

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/using-quicksight-parameters-and-controls-to-drive-interactivity-in-your-dashboards/

Answer (score 0):

> Is it through direct database queries or
>
> Does it intercept API calls from my web app's backend?

It will be through either direct database queries OR against a "snapshot" of your database tables at a given time (The data will be imported into [SPICE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/spice.html))

The only API calls that QuickSight appears to use are officially supported ones such as other AWS services or SaaS data sources highlighted at the bottom of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-data-sources.html